# QInputDialog action depending on item selection in ComboBox

Tags: c++, qt, events, user-interface, dialog

I have an input dialog (Qt) with three options in a combobox. I would like a different action be launched on the Ok depending on the item which was selected in the combobox. For now, I have

```
QInputDialog qDialog ;

QStringList items;
items << QString("Choice 1");
items << QString("Choice 2");
items << QString("Choice 3");

qDialog.setOptions(QInputDialog::UseListViewForComboBoxItems);
qDialog.setComboBoxItems(items);
qDialog.setWindowTitle("Choose action");

QObject::connect(&qDialog, SIGNAL(textValueChanged(const QString &)), 
           this, SLOT(onCompute(const QString &)));

qDialog.exec();
```

The slot `oncompute` performs a different action depending on the selected item in the combobox... but this is called when the user selects a new item in the box, not on click on ok.

How can i retrieve the item selected  on the combo box and perform action on click on Ok ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing `textValueChanged` by signal `textValueSelected` did it.

Answer (score 2):

Usual way of processing a modal dialog result is this:

```
QInputDialog qDialog;
...
if (qDialog.exec())
{
   onCompute(qDialog->textValue());
}
```

You execute a dialog, wait for the result and depending of what butting (ok or cancel) is clicked process the result or not.